# VB.NET / SQL for deleting database rows in a MS Access database

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access

I want to delete all the contents of a MS Access table however I am not sure how to set up my SQL to do so.

So far I have found this online:

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "DELETE * FROM QuestionResults WHERE Quizname = " & txtQuizName.Text & ";"
```

I have the connection to the database linked up due to my previous code, I am just unsure how to edit this code so that it deletes the contents of the table (i want it to delete every record, not the table itself)

```
Public provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
Public dataFile As String = "U:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\COMP4 Project\COMP4 Project\bin\Debug\QuizDatabase.accdb"

Public connString As String
Public myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
Public dr As OleDbDataReader

connString = provider & dataFile
myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
myConnection.Open()
```

Comment: You don't need the `*`. Also use parameters otherwise you're open to SQL injection.

Comment: Those DBObject ought not be global objects; they are all meant to be created, used and disposed in the smallest scope possible (with a few exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

Simply `DELETE FROM QuestionResults` without a `WHERE` clause will delete every row.

The alternative command `TRUNCATE TABLE QuestionResults` will be faster, however I don't know if Access/JET supports the `TRUNCATE` statement or not.

Note that you must not generate SQL using string concatenation. Your program will break if someone puts `"Baba O'Reilly"` into your `txtQuizName` textbox. Instead use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

What Dai said. Also you do not need an `OleDbDataReader`use an [OleDbCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true):

> Represents an SQL statement or stored procedure to execute against a data source.

Example use:

```
Dim command As New OleDbCommand(queryString, connection)
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```